# How to say "to prepare a place for sleeping" (for example to put a sheet, blanket and pillow on the bed)?

Tags: word-request, verbs

How to say "to prepare a place for sleeping"?
I mean "to put a sheet, blanket and pillow on the surface where someone will sleep (usually it's a bed)".

For example:

The host of a house says to his friend who wants to stay overnight at his house:
**(1)** *I "prepared a place to sleep" for you on the floor because unfortunately all beds are already occupied*.

A small child says to her mother:
**(2)** *Can you "prepare a place to sleep" for me in another room because mine is very cold*?

Comment: Much further discussion will be wholly valid but on the basic level Asked in that Question, no; never. Sorry, and English has no direct equivalent. The closest you could get would be to 'make (up) a bed' or to 'make a bed (up)' but neither comes close.

To 'prepare a place for sleeping' would always seem odd, but never be much misunderstood.

Wouldn't it be at least as interesting to learn what language this comes from and whether in that tongue, such a form would be common, or unusual?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

to **make a bed/the bed for you**: the general case

to make a bed for you **on the couch or sofa**
OR
to make up a bed for you on the couch
to make or make up a bed for you **on the floor** [with cushions or an air mattress for example]
to **put sheets, a blanket and a pillow [with a pillow case] on an air mattress** [the floor is implied]

Comment: Thanks. I thought "[to make the bed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-the-bed)" had the only meaning "to put the bed in order after sleeping".

Comment: @Loviii No, it can be both depending on context. Sometimes we *also* say: I will *make up a bed for you* on the couch or air mattress or on the floor.

Comment: +1 for 'make up a bed', often in a place where a bed is not usually to be found.

Comment: @lovii - "make the bed" to these ears is what you expected as far as neatening an already existing bed. "Make **a** bed..." would suggest to me preparing a new place for sleeping.

Comment: @Loviii If you wanted to reassure someone that the sheets have been changed and not only neatened after sleeping you could say that explicitly, e.g. "I changed the sheets for you on the bed downstairs"; at least in the midwest US this would be a common way to invite someone to stay there (or even pressure them slightly, like a parent trying to get an adult child to stay longer). However, the assumption would also be that whenever you're talking about a new person sleeping somewhere, it would have be polite to change the sheets so it's implied when you add a "for you" to "made the bed".

Comment: @BryanKrause I think your comment deserves to be a separate answer for completeness.

Comment: @MarkFoskey It's fine as a comment but goes way beyond the scope of the question, imo. The OP was not asking about "changing sheets".